# How old was King Hezekiah when he died?

Tags: ezekiel

King Hezekiah recovered from the inflammation or boil. He was given 15 years to live after he was healed. It was in the 14th year of his Kingship that he was healed.

Comment: Some textual references would be useful, from your own research on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

If Hezekiah, was 25 years old when He began to reign 726 BC-697 BC, which makes 29 years in His Kingship. He became sick in the 14 year of His reign, would have made Him 39 years old when He became sick. From that point 15 years was added to His life making him 54 years when He died.

Comment: Hello Larry, welcome to BHSE, so glad to have you here! Have you taken the tour of our site yet? We're a little different than other sites. Thanks. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour/